# localStorage is not defined (Angular Universal)

Tags: angular, typescript, local-storage, angular2-universal

I am using [universal-starter](https://github.com/angular/universal-starter) as backbone.

When my client starts, it read a token about user info from localStorage.

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  foo() {}

  bar() {}

  loadCurrentUser() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

    // do other things
  };
}
```

Everything works well, however I got this in the **server side** (terminal) because of server rendering:

> EXCEPTION: ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined

I got the idea from [ng-conf-2016-universal-patterns](https://github.com/gdi2290/ng-conf-2016-universal-patterns/tree/master/3-di-demo) that using Dependency Injection to solve this. But that demo is really old.

Say I have these two files now:

**main.broswer.ts**

```
export function ngApp() {
  return bootstrap(App, [
    // ...

    UserService
  ]);
}
```

**main.node.ts**

```
export function ngApp(req, res) {
  const config: ExpressEngineConfig = {
    // ...
    providers: [
      // ...
      UserService
    ]
  };

  res.render('index', config);
}
```

Right now they use both same UserService. Can someone give some codes to explain how to use different Dependency Injection to solve this?

If there is another better way rather than Dependency Injection, that will be cool too.

---

**UPDATE 1** I am using Angular 2 RC4, I tried @Martin's way. But even I import it, it still gives me error in the terminal below:

**Terminal (npm start)**

> /my-project/node_modules/@angular/core/src/di/reflective_provider.js:240
>           throw new reflective_exceptions_1.NoAnnotationError(typeOrFunc, params);
>           ^ Error: Cannot resolve all parameters for 'UserService'(Http, ?). Make sure that all the parameters are decorated with Inject or
>   have valid type annotations and that 'UserService' is decorated with
>   Injectable.

**Terminal (npm run watch)**

> error TS2304: Cannot find name 'LocalStorage'.

I guess it is somehow duplicated with the `LocalStorage` from `angular2-universal` (although I am not using `import { LocalStorage } from 'angular2-universal';`), but even I tried to change mine to `LocalStorage2`, still not work.

And in the meanwhile, my IDE WebStorm also shows red:

[image]

BTW, I found a `import { LocalStorage } from 'angular2-universal';`, but not sure how to use that.

---

**UPDATE 2**, I changed to (not sure whether there is a better way):

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Http } from '@angular/http';
import { LocalStorage } from '../../local-storage';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor (
    private _http: Http,
    @Inject(LocalStorage) private localStorage) {}  // <- this line is new

  loadCurrentUser() {
    const token = this.localStorage.getItem('token'); // here I change from `localStorage` to `this.localStorage`

    // …
  };
}
```

This solves the issue in **UPADAT 1**, but now I got error in the terminal:

> EXCEPTION: TypeError: this.localStorage.getItem is not a function

Comment: This can occur because of old browser version which doesn't support local & session storages afaik

Comment: Also, Safari in private browsing has `localStorage` disabled - should always do a check to see if it exists before using it.

Comment: Thanks for help. It works well on client side, right now I want to stop server rendering on the server side.

Comment: Do you have the correct path in your import for your local-storage.ts file?

Comment: @Martin yeah, I am sure it is correct, that is why `import { LocalStorage } from 'angular2-universal';` shows gray (gray means unused). If the path is wrong, it will show red color too

Comment: Am I the only one who thinks none of the answers below are clean and useful? What is universal about it, if I can't write `localStorage` both on client and server? I get it there's no `window` object whatever at server level, but come on, isn't there any dummy plug-and-go option for simulating a window thing on server for all client-level code to pass? Geeesh!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

**Update for newer versions of Angular**

`OpaqueToken` was superseded by `InjectionToken` which works much in the same way -- except it has a generic interface `InjectionToken<T>` which makes for better type checking and inference.

**Orginal Answer**

Two things:

1. You are not injecting any object that contains the localStorage object, you are trying to access it directly as a global. Any global access should be the first clue that something is wrong.
2. There is no window.localStorage in nodejs.

What you need to do is inject an adapter for localStorage that will work for both the browser and NodeJS. This will also give you testable code.

in local-storage.ts:

```
import { OpaqueToken } from '@angular/core';

export const LocalStorage = new OpaqueToken('localStorage');
```

In your main.browser.ts we will inject the actual localStorage object from your browser:

```
import {LocalStorage} from './local-storage.ts';

export function ngApp() {
  return bootstrap(App, [
    // ...

    UserService,
    { provide: LocalStorage, useValue: window.localStorage}
  ]);
```

And then in main.node.ts we will use an empty object:

```
... 
providers: [
    // ...
    UserService,
    {provide: LocalStorage, useValue: {getItem() {} }}
]
...
```

Then your service injects this:

```
import { LocalStorage } from '../local-storage';

export class UserService {

    constructor(@Inject(LocalStorage) private localStorage: LocalStorage) {}

    loadCurrentUser() {

        const token = this.localStorage.getItem('token');
        ...
    };
}
```

Comment: Hi Martin, where should I put first block of codes, because I saw `providers`. I am not sure where that file is.

Comment: That is a good question, I have updated my answer to address that.

Comment: I guess you mean `{ provide: LocalStorage, useValue: {}},`, `{ provide: LocalStorage, useValue: window.localStorage},`, and `{ provide: LocalStorage, useFactory: () => (window) ? window.localStorage : {}},`. But even I fix this, I still have a problem, check my question UPDATE part.

Comment: @Martin In main.browser.ts it is written { provide: LocalStorage, useValue: window.localStorage} meaning that LocalStorage object gets created referring to window.localStorage. In main.node.ts it is written {provide: LocalStorage, useValue: {getItem() {} }} meaning that LocalStorage gets created referring to nothing. And in service we are calling this.localStorage.getItem('token') meaning whenever a request gets called this service gets called which checks for the token. So now server needs to have that access for token. But am confused then how will it get that access?

Comment: @vyas the original http request for the initial page will contain the token if it is passed in a http header. The trick is to pass the original auth header in the http api request in your Angular app running on the server side. I do not know what the current best practice doing this is.

Comment: I get error in service `auth-token.service.ts (15,43): Cannot find name 'Inject'.` What can be a problem?

Comment: @Martin what is `local-storage.ts:`... I cant follow ur fix cause i dont know how that relates to my project or the question asked. Thank ahead

Comment: `has no exported member 'OpaqueToken'` in angular6... what is the solution for ng6?

Comment: @Omar, Use InjectorToken

Comment: When you use the provider with useValue, it seems to create a copy of window.localStorage. I also use setItem, and I had to use a factory (useFactory) instead to make sure changes are stored to window.localStorage, Like suggested in @darkseal answer

Comment: it just says window is not defined when providing provider value in browser file

Answer (score 53):

These steps resolved my issue:

**Step 1:** Run this command:

```
npm i localstorage-polyfill --save
```

**Step 2:** Add these two lines in **server.ts** file:

```
import 'localstorage-polyfill'

global['localStorage'] = localStorage;
```

Once you are done, run build command (eg: `npm run build:serverless`)

All set now. Start the server again and you can see the issue is resolved.

**Note:** Use localStorage not window.localStorage, eg: `localStorage.setItem(keyname, value)`

Comment: This one worked for me in Angular 9. I couldn't make the accepted answer work, maybe just because the project structure changed since then

Comment: @Tomasz Chudzik I tried the above solution but I am still getting the same error. Have you done anything extra apart from the steps mentioned above ?

Comment: this still works in Angular 12

Comment: Angular 14/Node 16.15 and still working fine.

Comment: Angular 15 and still working

Comment: Angular 16 (standalone app) still works.

Comment: Angular 17 still works

Answer (score 9):

In Angular 4 (and 5) you can easily deal with such issue with a simple function in the following way:

**app.module.ts**

```
@NgModule({
    providers: [
        { provide: 'LOCALSTORAGE', useFactory: getLocalStorage }
    ]
})
export class AppModule {
}

export function getLocalStorage() {
    return (typeof window !== "undefined") ? window.localStorage : null;
}
```

If you have a server/client split file **AppModule**, place it in the `app.module.shared.ts` file - the function won't break your code - unless you need to enforce completely different behaviours for the server and client builds; if that’s the case, it could be wiser to implement a custom class factory instead, just like it has been shown in other answers.

Anyway, once you're done with the provider implementation, you can inject the `LOCALSTORAGE` generic in any Angular component and check for the platform type with the Angular-native `isPlatformBrowser` function before using it:

```
import { PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser, isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';

@Injectable()
export class SomeComponent {
    constructor(
        @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: any,
        @Inject('LOCALSTORAGE') private localStorage: any) {

        // do something

    }

    NgOnInit() {
        if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
            // localStorage will be available: we can use it.
        }
        if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
            // localStorage will be null.
        }
    }
}
```

It’s worth noting that, since the `getLocalStorage()` function will return `null` if the window object isn’t available, you could just check for  `this.localStorage` nullability and entirely skip the platform type check. However, I strongly recommend the above approach as that function implementation (and return value) might be subject to change in the future; conversely, the  `isPlatformBrowser` / `isPlatformServer` return values are something that can be trusted by design.

For more info, check out [this blog post](https://www.ryadel.com/en/angular-5-access-window-document-localstorage-browser-types-angular-universal/) that I wrote on the topic.

Answer (score 6):

As wierd as this approach might seem, it is working, and I had to do none of the plumbing the other answers are suggesting.

**Step 1**

Install `localstorage-polyfill`: https://github.com/capaj/localstorage-polyfill

**Step 2**

Assuming you followed this step: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/stories-universal-rendering, you should have a file called, `server.js` in your project root folder.

In this `server.js` add this:

```
import 'localstorage-polyfill'

global['localStorage'] = localStorage;
```

**Step 3**

Rebuild your project, `npm run build:ssr`, and all should work fine now.

---

Does the above approach work? Yes, as far as I can tell.

Is it the best? Maybe not

Any performance issues? Not that I know of. Enlighten me.

However, as it stands now, this is the dumbest, most cleanest approach to getting my `localStorage` to pass

Comment: This is working on inspect element not on view source. Any fix for this ?

Comment: @subrat71 view source isn't the rendered version of the website. inspect element is the rendered version.

Answer (score 6):

You can use PLATFORM_ID token to check whether the current platform is browser or server.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject, PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html"
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

   constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) {  }

   ngOnInit() {

     // Client only code.
     if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
        let item = {key1: 'value1', key2: 'valu2' };
        localStorage.setItem( itemIndex, JSON.stringify(item) );
     }

   }
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

I am having a similar issue with Angular 4 + Universal following [steps here](https://coursetro.com/posts/code/68/Make-your-Angular-App-SEO-Friendly-(Angular-4-+-Universal)) to configure a SPA that can render at client side or server side.

I am using [oidc-client](https://github.com/IdentityModel/oidc-client-js) because I need my SPA to act as an OpenId Connect/Oauth2 client for my Identity Server.

The thing is that I was having the typical problem where localStorage or sessionStorage are not defined in server side (they only exist when there's a window object, therefore it wouldn't make sense for nodeJs to have these objects).

I have unsuccessfully tried the approach to mock the localStorage or sessionStorage and use the real one when in browser and an empty one in server.

But I came to the conclusion that for my needs I don't really need localStorage or sessionStorage to do anything in server side. If executed in NodeJs, simply skip the part where sessionStorage or localStorage is used, and the execution will then happen at client-side.

This would suffice:

```
console.log('Window is: ' + typeof window);
    this.userManager = typeof window !== 'undefined'? new oidc.UserManager(config) : null; //just don't do anything unless there is a window object
```

In client-side rendering it prints:
`Window is: object`

In nodeJs it prints:
`Window is: undefined`

The beauty of this is that Angular Universal will simply ignore the execution/rendering at server side when there is no window object, BUT that execution will be working fine when Angular Universal sends the page with javascript to the browser, therefore even if I am running my app in NodeJs eventually my browser prints the following:
`Window is: object`

I know this is not a proper answer for those who really need to access localStorage or sessionStorage in server side, but for most of the cases we use Angular Universal simply to render whatever is possible to render in server side, and for sending the things that can't be rendered to the browser to work normally.

Comment: Exactly what I was trying to implement as well +1

Answer (score 3):

I don't think this is a good solution, but I was stucked with the same problem using aspnetcore-spa generator and solved it this way:

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  foo() {}

  bar() {}

  loadCurrentUser() {
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
       const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
    }

    // do other things
  };
}
```

This condition prevents client code from running on the server-side where 'window' object doesn't exist.

Comment: thank you thank you thank you.  This is the only solution working in 2.2.4 for me.

Answer (score 3):

This is how we have it in our project, as per from this github **[comment](https://github.com/aspnet/JavaScriptServices/issues/377#issuecomment-336068756)**:

```
import { OnInit, PLATFORM_ID, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformServer, isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';

export class SomeClass implements OnInit {

    constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
            // do server side stuff
        }

        if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
           localStorage.setItem('myCats', 'Lissie & Lucky')
        }
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for @Martin's great help. But there are several places below need to be updated to get it work:

- `constructor` in **user.service.ts**
- `useValue` in **main.node.ts**, **main.browser.ts**

This is how my codes look like now.

I would love to accept @Martin's answer when he updated.

> BTW, I found a `import { LocalStorage } from 'angular2-universal';`, but
>   not sure how to use that.

**user.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';

import { LocalStorage } from '../local-storage';

@Injectable()
export class UserService {
  constructor (
    @Inject(LocalStorage) private localStorage) {}

  loadCurrentUser() {
    const token = localStorage.getItem('token');

    // do other things
  };
}
```

**local-storage.ts**

```
import { OpaqueToken } from '@angular/core';

export const LocalStorage = new OpaqueToken('localStorage');
```

**main.broswer.ts**

```
import { LocalStorage } from './local-storage';

export function ngApp() {
  return bootstrap(App, [
    // ...

    { provide: LocalStorage, useValue: window.localStorage},
    UserService
  ]);
}
```

**main.node.ts**

```
import { LocalStorage } from './local-storage';

export function ngApp(req, res) {
  const config: ExpressEngineConfig = {
    // ...
    providers: [
      // ...

      { provide: LocalStorage, useValue: { getItem() {} }},
      UserService
    ]
  };

  res.render('index', config);
}
```

Comment: I have updated my answer. Im glad I was able to get you most of the way there.

Comment: I get error in service `auth-token.service.ts (15,43): Cannot find name 'Inject'.` What can be a problem?

Answer (score 1):

I have no sufficient knowledge of preparing angular apps to run serverside. But in the similar scenario for react & nodejs, what needs to be done is to let server know what `localStorage` is. For example:

```
//Stub for localStorage
(global as any).localStorage = {
  getItem: function (key) {
    return this[key];
  },
  setItem: function (key, value) {
    this[key] = value;
  }
};
```

Hope this can be of any help to you.

Answer (score 1):

LocalStorage not implemented by the server side. We need to choose to write depend on platform code or use a cookie for save and read data.
`ngx-cookie` is best solution(that i know) for work with cookie on server and browser.
You can write extend Storage class with cookie work:
[universal.storage.ts](https://github.com/Angular-RU/angular-universal-starter/blob/master/src/app/shared/storage/universal.storage.ts)

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie';

@Injectable()
export class UniversalStorage implements Storage {
  [index: number]: string;
  [key: string]: any;
  length: number;
  cookies: any;

  constructor(private cookieService: CookieService) {}

  public clear(): void {
    this.cookieService.removeAll();
  }

  public getItem(key: string): string {
    return this.cookieService.get(key);
  }

  public key(index: number): string {
    return this.cookieService.getAll().propertyIsEnumerable[index];
  }

  public removeItem(key: string): void {
    this.cookieService.remove(key);
  }

  public setItem(key: string, data: string): void {
    this.cookieService.put(key, data);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Solved "getItem undefined" issue by below lines :

```
if(window.localStorage){
      return window.localStorage.getItem('user');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Angular Universal should understand whether the function is for Browser or Server

Use the simple option like

**Method 1**

```
import { PLATFORM_ID } from '@angular/core';
import { isPlatformBrowser, isPlatformServer } from '@angular/common';

constructor(@Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object) { 
    // constructor code
}

ngOnInit() {
    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
        // Client only code. Local storage code
    }
    if (isPlatformServer(this.platformId)) {
        // Server only code. Local storage code
    }
}
```

**Method 2**

```
    import {  PLATFORM_ID} from '@angular/core';
    import { isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
    
    @Component({
      selector: 'app-navigation',
      templateUrl: './navigation.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./navigation.component.scss'],
      changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush,
    })
    export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit {
      private isBrowser: boolean = false;
    
      constructor(
        @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object
      ) {
        this.isBrowser = isPlatformBrowser(platformId);
      }
    
      ngOnInit(): void {
          if (this.isBrowser) {
            var retrievedLocale = localStorage?.getItem('preferredLocale');
          }
        }

      changeLocale(category: any): void {
         if (this.isBrowser) {
            window.localStorage.setItem('preferredLocale', locale.code);
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: In which file would this code go?

Comment: In component.ts file. For e.g: The code updated in NAVIGATION.COMPONENT.ts and its respective NAVIGATION.COMPONENT.html file the click method is written. ========CODE================

<ul class="nav__top-nav-locales-country-language-locale">
 <li class="list">
 <span  class="language"  *ngFor="let locale of country?.items; let i = index"><button class="nav" (click)="changeLocale(locale.locale); isOpen = false">{{ locale.language }}/button></span></li></ul>

Answer (score 0):

In my case what helped was simply checking if the document is defined before checking the localStorage.

```
  if (typeof document !== 'undefined') {

      localStorage.getItem("item")

  }
```

Answer (score -2):

I have also ran in to the same issue.
You can write inside 'isBrowser' check by importing below statement.

`import { isBrowser } from 'angular2-universal';`

Comment: Elaborate your answer please, nothing can be learnt from above two lines.

Comment: Please complete your answer

Comment: isBrowser is part of angular universal module which gives a value true if the app is running in browser and false if it is running in node or server.