# npm test is fine, but it also raises the error uncaught at askBackend ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined

Tags: javascript, jestjs, create-react-app

I am now starting to test my reducer in a Reactjs application. I use `localStorage`.

`utils.js`

```
export const getAuthToken = () => {
  return localStorage.getItem('authToken');
};

export const setAuthToken = (token) => {
  localStorage.setItem('authToken', token);
};

export const removeAuthToken = () => {
  localStorage.removeItem('authToken');
};

export const prepareJWTHeader = (token) => {
  return 'JWT ' + token
};
```

**Softwares:**
`npm: 5.6.0`
`node: v9.2.0`
`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "f1",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@amcharts/amcharts3-react": "^3.1.0",
    "ajv": "^6.5.0",
    "amcharts3": "^3.21.12",
    "antd": "^3.6.1",
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
    "jquery": "^3.3.1",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "npm-check-updates": "^2.14.2",
    "react": "^16.4.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.0",
    "react-live": "^1.10.1",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "react-router-bootstrap": "^0.24.4",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.1",
    "react-tabs": "^2.2.2",
    "reactstrap": "^6.0.1",
    "recharts": "^1.0.0-beta.10",
    "redux": "^3.7.2",
    "redux-form": "^7.2.3",
    "redux-saga": "^0.16.0",
    "semantic-ui-css": "^2.3.1",
    "semantic-ui-react": "^0.80.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

I made my project from `create-react-app`. Its version is `1.4.3`
In my project I had checked with this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46072312/referenceerror-localstorage-is-not-defined), but I do not understand. Why I still getting this error

Here is my full terminal when run `npm test`

```
PASS  src/App.test.js
  ✓ renders without crashing (4ms)

Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        0.295s, estimated 8s
Ran all test suites.

  console.error node_modules/redux-saga/lib/internal/utils.js:240
    uncaught at askBackend ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
        at Object.<anonymous>.exports.removeAuthToken (/Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/src/utils.js:34:3)
        at Object.<anonymous>.exports.VerifyTokenReducer (/Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/src/containers/reducers.js:20:34)
        at combination (/Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/node_modules/redux/lib/combineReducers.js:133:29)
        at dispatch (/Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/node_modules/redux/lib/createStore.js:178:22)
        at /Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/node_modules/redux-saga/lib/internal/middleware.js:72:22
        at dispatch (/Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/node_modules/redux/lib/applyMiddleware.js:45:18)
        at /Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/node_modules/redux-saga/lib/internal/utils.js:265:12
        at /Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/node_modules/redux-saga/lib/internal/proc.js:500:52
        at exec (/Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/node_modules/redux-saga/lib/internal/scheduler.js:25:5)
        at flush (/Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/node_modules/redux-saga/lib/internal/scheduler.js:66:5)
        at asap (/Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/node_modules/redux-saga/lib/internal/scheduler.js:39:5)
        at Array.<anonymous> (/Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/node_modules/redux-saga/lib/internal/channel.js:197:27)
        at Object.emit (/Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/node_modules/redux-saga/lib/internal/channel.js:38:13)
        at /Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/node_modules/redux-saga/lib/internal/middleware.js:73:21
        at Object.validateToken (/Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/node_modules/redux/lib/bindActionCreators.js:7:12)
        at new Container (/Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/src/containers/components/Container.js:37:16)
        at constructClassInstance (/Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:11333:18)
        at updateClassComponent (/Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:13036:7)
        at beginWork (/Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:13715:14)
        at performUnitOfWork (/Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15741:12)
        at workLoop (/Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15780:24)
        at renderRoot (/Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:15820:7)
        at performWorkOnRoot (/Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16437:22)
        at performWork (/Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16358:7)
        at performSyncWork (/Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16330:3)
        at requestWork (/Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16230:5)
        at scheduleWork$1 (/Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16096:11)
        at scheduleRootUpdate (/Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16663:3)
        at updateContainerAtExpirationTime (/Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16690:10)
        at updateContainer (/Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16717:10)
        at ReactRoot.Object.<anonymous>.ReactRoot.render (/Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17000:3)
        at /Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17140:14
        at unbatchedUpdates (/Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:16557:10)
        at legacyRenderSubtreeIntoContainer (/Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17136:5)
        at Object.render (/Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/node_modules/react-dom/cjs/react-dom.development.js:17195:12)
        at Object.<anonymous>.it (/Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/src/App.test.js:7:22)
        at Object.asyncFn (/Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmine-async.js:68:30)
        at resolve (/Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:38:12)
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at mapper (/Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:31:21)
        at Promise.resolve.then.el (/Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/node_modules/p-map/index.js:46:16)
        at <anonymous>
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
```

I think it is false negative alarm. How to get rid of the error messages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually your code runs in a browser. So it has access to the `localStorage`. Your tests are running in a virtual dom (created in plain javascript = `jsdom`). You can see it in the `test` script: `"react-scripts test --env=jsdom"`.

When running the tests in a specific testenvironment it doesn't know `localStorage`.

You can try to mock it in your test files. It could be like this:

```
// In localStorageMock.js
class LocalStorageMock {
  constructor() {
    this.store = {}
  }

  clear() {
    this.store = {}
  }

  getItem(key) {
    return this.store[key] || null
  }

  setItem(key, value) {
    this.store[key] = value
  }

  removeItem(key) {
    delete this.store[key]
  }
}

const localStorageMock = new LocalStorageMock();
export default localStorageMock;

// in utils.js
import localStorage from './localStorageMock';
```

*Source: The class-example is from @Dmitriy from an other [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32911630/how-do-i-deal-with-localstorage-in-jest-tests).*

**Hint:** You should check for the environment before including the `localStorageMock`. If not it will also be used when running the code in your browser.

**EDIT:** [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40449434/mocking-globals-in-jest) is a good explanation on how to mock globals in jest. I think its better to import the mock in your test files instead of the `utils.js`.

Comment: I am aware that runner is server side, but how can I tell the runner that this is context of `Browser`? In short How do I `localStorageMock` to the project?

Comment: Just copy and paste like you said! Thank you very much!

Comment: `App.test.js` has only `'renders without crashing'`. I did not test anything or call the `localStorage` yet. I agree that I should import `localStorageMock` in the `TestFile.js`, but I can't :(