# Javascript locally import header on the fly based on runner arguments

Tags: javascript, jestjs

In `Python` I can locally import the `headers` on the fly. Right now I am working on the `Reactjs` and `localStorage` which is normally run on client. Now it has running in the server side. The problem has been address [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50755559/npm-test-is-fine-but-it-also-raises-the-error-uncaught-at-askbackend-referencee)
But I am accidentally commit the `mock` class to source code. So I started to use `process.env` in order to do `local import` like `Python`

**package.json**

```
{
  ...,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  }
}
```

I know how to use `process.env` from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25112510/how-to-set-environment-variables-from-within-package-json-node-js). But I still can not get out from the issue. I got `'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level`

```
export const getAuthToken = () => {
  if (process.env === 'development'){
    import localStorage from './localStorageMock';
  }
  return localStorage.getItem('authToken');
};
```

**Question:**
How to do locally import like `Python` in `Javascript`?
If not how can I solve this issue?

**Attempt1:**
`localStorageMock2.js`. I try another syntax.

```
function LocalStorageMock(){
  this.store = {};

  this.getItem = function(key){
    return this.store[key] || null
  };
  this.setItem = function(key, value) {
    this.store[key] = value
  };

  this.removeItem = function(key) {
    delete this.store[key]
  };

}
```

const localStorageMock = new LocalStorageMock();
export default localStorageMock;

**Trackback1:**
When I look at the `cache` object
`console.log(cache);`

```
{ default:
  LocalStorageMock {
  store: {},
  getItem: [Function],
  setItem: [Function],
  removeItem: [Function] } }
```

I think I see `removeItem` function. But no luck.
`console.log(typeof cache.removeItem);`

```
undefined
```

Then like I expected. It raises the exception.
`return cache.removeItem('authToken');`

```
console.error node_modules/redux-saga/lib/internal/utils.js:240
      uncaught at askBackend TypeError: cache.removeItem is not a function
          at Object.<anonymous>.exports.removeAuthToken (/Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/src/utils.js:50:16)
          at Object.<anonymous>.exports.VerifyTokenReducer (/Users/sarit/study/HT6MInterface/f1/src/containers/reducers.js:20:34)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you very much to [him](https://github.com/panigrah). He always support newbie through gitter channel. Here is the complete solution to my problem.

```
export const myCache = () => {
  //Fix the test when runner is on serverside

  const tmp = Object.assign({}, process.argv);
  const cache = (tmp[4] === '--env=jsdom') ? require("./localStorageMock2") : localStorage;
  if (tmp[4] === '--env=jsdom') {
    const cache = require("./localStorageMock2");
    return cache.default;
  } else {
    return localStorage;
  }
};
```

I was totally forgot `require` syntax. Since I am practicing pure ES6.