# Angular Universal error with localStorage

Tags: angular, universal

i have angular 4 project and i decided to convert it to angular universal , i followed this tutorial 
https://coursetro.com/posts/code/68/Make-your-Angular-App-SEO-Friendly-(Angular-4-+-Universal)

but i got this problem when i run

```
npm run start
```

the problem is displayed

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: sessionStorage is not defined ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: { ReferenceError: sessionStorage is not defined
    at new Settings (E:\Angular\readuni\src\app\settings\settings.ts:2:17)
    at _createClass (E:\Angular\readuni\packages\core\src\view\ng_module.ts:148:1)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (E:\Angular\readuni\packages\core\src\view\ng_module.ts:122:1)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (E:\Angular\readuni\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:9520:17)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (E:\Angular\readuni\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:10594:16)
    at resolveDep (E:\Angular\readuni\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:11082:45)
    at createClass (E:\Angular\readuni\packages\core\src\view\provider.ts:360:1)
    at createDirectiveInstance (E:\Angular\readuni\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:10783:37)
    at createViewNodes (E:\Angular\readuni\packages\core\src\view\view.ts:359:1)
    at createRootView (E:\Angular\readuni\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:12114:5)
  __zone_symbol__currentTask:
   ZoneTask {
     _zone:
      Zone {
        _properties: {},
        _parent: null,
        _name: '<root>',
        _zoneDelegate: [Object] },
     runCount: 0,
     _zoneDelegates: null,
     _state: 'notScheduled',
     type: 'microTask',
     source: 'Promise.then',
     data: undefined,
     scheduleFn: undefined,
     cancelFn: null,
     callback: [Function],
     invoke: [Function] } } ReferenceError: sessionStorage is not defined
    at new Settings (E:\Angular\readuni\src\app\settings\settings.ts:2:17)
    at _createClass (E:\Angular\readuni\packages\core\src\view\ng_module.ts:148:1)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (E:\Angular\readuni\packages\core\src\view\ng_module.ts:122:1)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (E:\Angular\readuni\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:9520:17)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (E:\Angular\readuni\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:10594:16)
    at resolveDep (E:\Angular\readuni\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:11082:45)
    at createClass (E:\Angular\readuni\packages\core\src\view\provider.ts:360:1)
    at createDirectiveInstance (E:\Angular\readuni\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:10783:37)
    at createViewNodes (E:\Angular\readuni\packages\core\src\view\view.ts:359:1)
    at createRootView (E:\Angular\readuni\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:12114:5)
ERROR { ReferenceError: sessionStorage is not defined
    at new Settings (E:\Angular\readuni\src\app\settings\settings.ts:2:17)
    at _createClass (E:\Angular\readuni\packages\core\src\view\ng_module.ts:148:1)
    at _createProviderInstance$1 (E:\Angular\readuni\packages\core\src\view\ng_module.ts:122:1)
    at resolveNgModuleDep (E:\Angular\readuni\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:9520:17)
    at NgModuleRef_.get (E:\Angular\readuni\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:10594:16)
    at resolveDep (E:\Angular\readuni\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:11082:45)
    at createClass (E:\Angular\readuni\packages\core\src\view\provider.ts:360:1)
    at createDirectiveInstance (E:\Angular\readuni\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:10783:37)
    at createViewNodes (E:\Angular\readuni\packages\core\src\view\view.ts:359:1)
    at createRootView (E:\Angular\readuni\node_modules\@angular\core\bundles\core.umd.js:12114:5)
  __zone_symbol__currentTask:
   ZoneTask {
     _zone:
      Zone {
        _properties: [Object],
        _parent: [Object],
        _name: 'angular',
        _zoneDelegate: [Object] },
     runCount: 0,
     _zoneDelegates: null,
     _state: 'notScheduled',
     type: 'microTask',
     source: 'Promise.then',
     data: undefined,
     scheduleFn: undefined,
     cancelFn: null,
     callback: [Function],
     invoke: [Function] } }
```

i'm using in my project sessionStorage
example 
setting.ts

```
export class Settings{
    adminPerm = sessionStorage.getItem("isAdmin");
    adminPrem = sessionStorage.getItem("isAdmin");
    isLogged = sessionStorage.getItem("loggedIn");
    apiUrl = 'http://sitesite.me/api/';
    checkLogin = sessionStorage.getItem("loggedIn");
}
```

Comment: Practically a dupe... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39085632/localstorage-is-not-defined-angular-universal

Answer (score 1):

There is no `sessionStorage` or any other browser specific global objects on the server side since it runs within nodejs. You should use [`isPlatformBrowser`](https://angular.io/api/common/isPlatformBrowser) to identify whether your are now in the browser before to execute code like this.