# localstorage is not deffined angular && .net core 2.0

Tags: angular, typescript, .net-core

I'm following this tutorial https://www.pointblankdevelopment.com.au/blog/113/aspnet-core-20-angular-24-user-registration-and-login-tutorial-example
For user registrations and login

But when I run application I'm getting next error:
[image]

I read on few articles about this but nothing helped me.
Here is my code on git:[Code on GIT](https://github.com/danijel88/AngularPDM)
Can anyone help me to understand where I made mistake and how can fix it ?

Thanks and Regards,

Comment: i think u are facing this issue in universal ( server side rendering ) only and not in browser, right ?

Comment: I'm running directly from Visual Studio, it is not deployed to the server. So, not sure. How can I check this and let you know correct answer ?

Comment: Aren't you compiling and running it in browser ?  Line 10 in [this file](https://github.com/danijel88/AngularPDM/blob/master/AngularPDM/ClientApp/app/components/_guards/auth.guard.ts) is causing the error.

Comment: You should checkout [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39085632/localstorage-is-not-defined-angular-universal)

Comment: Yes, I'm compiling and running it in browser. I will try your suggested answer and let it you know.

Comment: That is not helping me...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158587/discussion-between-danijel-boksan-and-dhyey).

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39085632/localstorage-is-not-defined-angular-universal

Answer (score 0):

You need use "***isPlatformBrowser***"

Import:

```
import { isPlatformServer, isPlatformBrowser } from '@angular/common';
```

and declare in the constructor:

```
constructor(private _http: Http, @Inject(PLATFORM_ID) private platformId: Object)...
```

use:

```
public setValue(value){

    if (isPlatformBrowser(this.platformId)) {
            localStorage.setItem('varX', value);
            ........
        }
}
```