# ng build is running indefinitely

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-universal, angular-local-storage

I am getting this error when I am doing ng serve

```
ERROR ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
    at _ShoppingCartService.eval (/Users/sunilsarode/SHOP/oshop/src/app/services/shopping-cart.service.ts:38:7)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at eval (/Users/sunilsarode/SHOP/oshop/.angular/vite-root/oshop/chunk-KS6ILM5U.mjs:94:61)
    at ZoneAwarePromise (/Users/sunilsarode/SHOP/oshop/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:1353:21)
    at Module.__async (/Users/sunilsarode/SHOP/oshop/.angular/vite-root/oshop/chunk-KS6ILM5U.mjs:78:10)
    at _ShoppingCartService.getCartOrCreateCartId (/Users/sunilsarode/SHOP/oshop/src/app/services/shopping-cart.service.ts:35:38)
    at _ShoppingCartService.eval (/Users/sunilsarode/SHOP/oshop/src/app/services/shopping-cart.service.ts:24:29)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at eval (/Users/sunilsarode/SHOP/oshop/.angular/vite-root/oshop/chunk-KS6ILM5U.mjs:94:61)
    at ZoneAwarePromise (/Users/sunilsarode/SHOP/oshop/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:1353:21)
ERROR ReferenceError: localStorage is not defined
    at _ShoppingCartService.eval (/Users/sunilsarode/SHOP/oshop/src/app/services/shopping-cart.service.ts:38:7)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at eval (/Users/sunilsarode/SHOP/oshop/.angular/vite-root/oshop/chunk-KS6ILM5U.mjs:94:61)
    at ZoneAwarePromise (/Users/sunilsarode/SHOP/oshop/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:1353:21)
    at Module.__async (/Users/sunilsarode/SHOP/oshop/.angular/vite-root/oshop/chunk-KS6ILM5U.mjs:78:10)
    at _ShoppingCartService.getCartOrCreateCartId (/Users/sunilsarode/SHOP/oshop/src/app/services/shopping-cart.service.ts:35:38)
    at _ShoppingCartService.eval (/Users/sunilsarode/SHOP/oshop/src/app/services/shopping-cart.service.ts:24:29)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at eval (/Users/sunilsarode/SHOP/oshop/.angular/vite-root/oshop/chunk-KS6ILM5U.mjs:94:61)
    at ZoneAwarePromise (/Users/sunilsarode/SHOP/oshop/node_modules/zone.js/fesm2015/zone-node.js:1353:21)
```

I tried following the solution and the error is gone, but now I am doing ng build, which runs indefinitely.

```
  private async getCartOrCreateCartId(): Promise<string> {
    let cartId;
    if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
      cartId = localStorage?.getItem('cartId');
    }

    if (!cartId) {
      let result = await this.create();
      if (result.key) {
        if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
          localStorage?.setItem('cartId', result.key);
        }
        return result.key;
      }
      return '';
    } else {
      return cartId;
    }
  }

  private create() {
    return this.db.list('/shopping-carts').push({
      dateCreated: new Date().getTime(),
    });
  }
```

I also read this answer [localStorage is not defined (Angular Universal)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39085632/localstorage-is-not-defined-angular-universal)

I do not have any local-storage.ts file, also I am working on the angular standalone component and hence I do not have any app.module.ts file.

angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "oshop": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:application",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/oshop",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "browser": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "server": "src/main.server.ts",
            "prerender": true,
            "ssr": {
              "entry": "server.ts"
            }
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "optimization": false,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.development.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "oshop:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "oshop:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "buildTarget": "oshop:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        },
        "deploy": {
          "builder": "@angular/fire:deploy",
          "options": {
            "version": 2
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "buildTarget": "oshop:build:production",
              "serveTarget": "oshop:serve:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildTarget": "oshop:build:development",
              "serveTarget": "oshop:serve:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

server.ts

```
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { CommonEngine } from '@angular/ssr';
import express from 'express';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'node:url';
import { dirname, join, resolve } from 'node:path';
import bootstrap from './src/main.server';

// The Express app is exported so that it can be used by serverless Functions.
export function app(): express.Express {
  const server = express();
  const serverDistFolder = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
  const browserDistFolder = resolve(serverDistFolder, '../browser');
  const indexHtml = join(serverDistFolder, 'index.server.html');

  const commonEngine = new CommonEngine();

  server.set('view engine', 'html');
  server.set('views', browserDistFolder);

  // Example Express Rest API endpoints
  // server.get('/api/**', (req, res) => { });
  // Serve static files from /browser
  server.get('*.*', express.static(browserDistFolder, {
    maxAge: '1y'
  }));

  // All regular routes use the Angular engine
  server.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
    const { protocol, originalUrl, baseUrl, headers } = req;

    commonEngine
      .render({
        bootstrap,
        documentFilePath: indexHtml,
        url: `${protocol}://${headers.host}${originalUrl}`,
        publicPath: browserDistFolder,
        providers: [{ provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: baseUrl }],
      })
      .then((html) => res.send(html))
      .catch((err) => next(err));
  });

  return server;
}

function run(): void {
  const port = process.env['PORT'] || 4000;

  // Start up the Node server
  const server = app();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Node Express server listening on http://localhost:${port}`);
  });
}

run();
```

package.json

```
{
  "name": "oshop",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "serve:ssr:oshop": "node dist/oshop/server/server.mjs"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^17.0.10",
    "@angular/animations": "^17.0.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^17.0.5",
    "@angular/common": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/fire": "^17.0.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/material": "^17.0.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-server": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^17.0.0",
    "@angular/ssr": "^17.0.10",
    "express": "^4.18.2",
    "firebase": "^10.7.1",
    "firebase-tools": "^13.0.3",
    "g": "^2.0.1",
    "localstorage-polyfill": "^1.0.1",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.14.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^17.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.17",
    "@types/jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.18.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~5.1.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.2.2"
  }
}
```

Can somebody explain to me what is the issue here and how to resolve it? Thanks.

Comment: `LocalStorage` is not available when doing SSR.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler can you please explain more, thanks.